# Over voltage protection for 5v differential line

Tags: differential, encoder, over-voltage-protection

I am working on a stepper motor driver that will use 48V as a power source, this driver will have encoder interface. The encoder has 3 differential lines which will only tolerate 5V.

I want to protect those lines in case of accidently connected to any voltage higher than 5V.
The power supply in my situation will be able to source 10A @ 48V

This is how I will do it but I am not sure if this is the proper way or not since this configuration is only valid for short term over-voltage protection (milliseconds I guess)
Should I add rapid acting fuse in series with each line or it will not be fast enough to protect the line input?
My question is how to do over voltage protection for this configuration considering a low cost solution?

**EDIT:**
I was thinking about adding 220~470 ohm resistor in series with each line for current limiting in case the line got connected to higher source than 5V, but I am not sure what will happen with the signal integrity since this is a differential line!

[image]